# jQuery: Finding cloned child in cloned parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Let's say I have this jQuery extension method:

```
$.fn.foobar = function() {
    var clone = this.parent().clone();
};
```

After I've gotten `clone`, how can I find the cloned child element that is the same as `this`?

Will this work?

```
$.fn.foobar = function() {
    var clone = this.parent().clone();
    var cloneOfThis = clone.find(this);
};
```

Or this?

```
$.fn.foobar = function() {
    var clone = this.parent().clone();
    var self = this;
    var cloneOfThis;
    clone.children().each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this === self) {
            cloneOfThis = $this;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Why not clone the parent and the current element? (besides that `this` in a jQuery extension refers to an array of elements that the selector selected).

Comment: @Felix - It would seem that if you cloned both, then you would end up with 2 unique clones of `this`. One directly cloned, and one cloned along with the parent.

Comment: @patrick dw: True, it depends on what the OP actually wants to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try giving it some unique class that could be used to refer back to the proper element.

```
$.fn.foobar = function() {
      // Add a class to "this", then clone its parent
    var clonedParent = this.addClass("someUniqueClass").parent().clone();
      // Reference the new clone of "this" inside the cloned parent,
      //   then remove the class
    var cloneOfThis = clonedParent.find(".someUniqueClass").removeClass("someUniqueClass");
      // Remove the class from the original
    this.removeClass("someUniqueClass");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a reference comparison to work here because `this` isn't in the clone, it's the original element, it wasn't moved.  An element *like* the one you cloned is in the cloned parent, so you have to decide what "the same" means, is it the same ID, the same HTML content, the same value?

You just need to pick a value you *can* compare, because the reference won't work here...you can't find something that isn't there :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking patrick dw's answer a little further, and incorporating Felix King's comment, I would suggest the following:

```
$.fn.foobar = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        // Add a class to "this", then clone its parent
        var clonedParent = $(this).addClass("someUniqueClass").parent().clone();

        // Reference the new clone of "this" inside the cloned parent
        var cloneOfThis = clonedParent.find(".someUniqueClass");

        //remove the unique class to preserve the original state (other than the clone which is now present)
        $('.someUniqueClass').add(cloneOfThis).removeClass('someUniqueClass');
    });
};
```

Comment: Inside the `.each()`, you can't do `this.addClass`. And `$('.someUniqueClass').removeClass` wouldn't remove the class from the clones, because they're not yet part of the DOM.

Comment: @patrick dw - good points, thanks.  I've edited my answer to reflect them.

Comment: Ender - Just remember that you're in an `.each()` loop. So if there are 50 elements, you'll be selecting `$('.someUniqueClass')` from the DOM 50 times, as well as adding the cloned item and removing the class from all of them 50 times.